# How do I query for a List<String> using DBUtils?

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbutils

Looking over the [DBUtils API docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/handlers/package-summary.html), I cannot see if it's possible to query for a `List<String>` in the same way that I could query a `List<MyBean>` using BeanListHandler.

I could either do it be creating a Bean that wraps the String and use BeanListHandler or possibly return a `List<Object[]>` and fish out my Strings that way.

But is there a more direct way where DBUtils can pass back a `List<String>` for a query that produces a bunch of String values from a varchar table column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try a `ColumnListHandler`, and tell it which column to use from your query.  You can pass in either the column index or column name to extract.  Something like:

```
List<String> strings = runner.query("SELECT my_col FROM my_table",
                                    new ColumnListHandler<String>(1));
                                    // gets first column
```

Internally it uses [`ResultSet#getObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29) which returns a `String` if the selected column is a string type, so make sure you're not selecting a numeric or date type or something (and if you are, cast or otherwise convert it to a char type in the select query).

Comment: good adivice, you can extend as "select col1||','||col2... cols from my_table" bunch of string values.